# CSS ">" vs " > "?

Tags: css, syntax, css-selectors, whitespace

In CSS `.a > .b` is the same as `.a>.b`, but which of this two is the more correct notation? I see that in Chrome developer tools the 2nd variant is used

Answer (score 10):

Neither is "more correct"; both are equally valid. The only thing that the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax) says is that whitespace surrounding combinators is optional (emphasis mine):

> *Combinators* are: whitespace, "greater-than sign" (U+003E, `>`), "plus sign" (U+002B, `+`) and "tilde" (U+007E, `~`). **White space may appear between a combinator and the simple selectors around it.** Only the characters "space" (U+0020), "tab" (U+0009), "line feed" (U+000A), "carriage return" (U+000D), and "form feed" (U+000C) can occur in whitespace. Other space-like characters, such as "em-space" (U+2003) and "ideographic space" (U+3000), are never part of whitespace.

Note that the descendant combinator itself is represented by a space character; if the only characters surrounding two compound selectors are whitespace characters then they are treated as a descendant combinator. In your example, the child combinator `>` can either be surrounded by whitespace, or not; there is no difference.

You can see an example of both whitespace and whitespace-less syntaxes in the spec itself, coincidentally [also in the section describing the child combinator `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators). Notice, again with emphasis mine, that the spec even mentions explicitly where whitespace has been omitted, to demonstrate that it is in fact completely optional:

> Examples:
>
> The following selector represents a `p` element that is child of `body`:
>
> ```
> body > p
> ```
>
> The following example combines descendant combinators and child combinators.
>
> ```
> div ol>li p
> ```
>
> It represents a `p` element that is a descendant of an `li` element; the `li` element must be the child of an `ol` element; the `ol` element must be a descendant of a `div`. **Notice that the optional white space around the ">" combinator has been left out.**

As mentioned by others, when *writing* CSS, whitespace is good to have for readability purposes; if file size is a concern, consider minifying and/or compressing your stylesheet during post-production (minifying typically strips non-significant whitespace out for you, which can include whitespace around combinators). The only reason you would choose not to use whitespace when authoring CSS is a matter of coding style, and that is still technically valid, even if frowned upon.

Answer (score 4):

The first is preferred for readability but it is not necessary, the compiler does not care besides the fact that it has less characters to read in the second one.

I can assure you that *all* humans prefer the first version because it makes our jobs a lot easier while computers prefer the second, but only slightly. I'd recommend only using the second option if you minify your CSS only when deploying to a live site as doing so will save time for all the developers working with it

Answer (score 3):

The only benefit of the second notation is the additional saving of a few bytes by removing the redundant whitespace. Typically this would also be the end result of minifying your CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if you want your code to be easily readable, then use the:

```
.a > .b
```

However, if you want the stylesheet to load faster (though not very much faster), you may want to use:

```
.a>.b
```