# What's the difference between CSS child selector without space "a>b" and with space "a > b"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there any difference between both of them?

Example 1:

```
a>b{
  display: block;
}
```

Example 2:

```
a > b{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yes, one with spaces and the other is not. That's it

Comment: The difference is the latter requires you to type 2 more characters (*No differerence*)

Comment: There is no difference when it comes to applying the CSS property. Are you facing any issue with that ?

Comment: @nabanita No. I was just wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS is very forgiving. The CSS selectors specification mentiones that whitespaces around combinators (like your `>` here) are optional:

> The following selector represents a p element that is child of body:
>
> ```
> body > p
> ```
>
> The following example combines descendant combinators and child combinators.
>
> ```
> div ol>li p
> ```
>
> It represents a p element that is a descendant of an li element; the li element must be the child of an ol element; the ol element must be a descendant of a div. Notice that **the optional white space** around the ">" combinator has been left out.
>
> — [Section 8.2 of the CSS Selectors Level 3 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators)

To further back this up, the specification's *Grammar* section makes this really apparent with an implementation approach:

> ```
> combinator
>   /* combinators can be surrounded by whitespace */
>   : S+ | S* [ '>' | '+' | '~' | COLUMN | '/' IDENT '/' ] S*
>   ;
> ```
>
> — [Section 10 of the CSS Selectors Level 3 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar)

For this reason, the following are all valid as CSS parsers should simply strip the spaces out:

```css
a>b {}
a > b {}
a> b {}
a >b {}
a     >    b {}
```

So to answer your question: no, there is no difference.

As for which one you should use, however: that's purely a question of personal preference. For me, I'd opt for `a > b`, simply because I feel it makes it easier to read, but if you want to type `a>b` or even `a    >    b` it's entirely up to you - although anyone who has to read your code will probably not be your number 1 fan with the latter approach!

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581885/css-vs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091583/whitespace-in-css-selectors (and, albeit not related to combinators, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930898/what-are-the-rules-around-whitespace-in-attribute-selectors).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such difference. See the snippet below for demo:

```css
.a>.b{
  color: red;
}

.c > .d{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  Class a
  <div class="b">
    Class b
  </div>
</div>

<div class="c">
  Class c
  <div class="d">
    Class d
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all there is no effect space between or not, both will work.**

Example will work with following DOM structure:

```
<a><b></b></a>
```

Comment: What? there is such a thing to select a parent in CSS? Mind blown

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two.

Comment: You may wanna explain a little bit further why this is not the case. I.e. reference a documentation.